On the "Credentials" page -> "CREATE CREDENTIALS" -> "OAuth client ID" , I don't see "Chrome App" in Application Type
I am trying to setup up Google Cloud Console project and OAuth credentials specifically for a Chrome Extension using Firebase.
On the "Credentials" page -> "CREATE CREDENTIALS" -> "OAuth client ID" , I don't see "Chrome App" in Application Type
